# Rayleigh-Schrodinger perturbation of double-well

Tags: perturbation-theory

Might be a silly question but anyway. I know how to use the Rayleigh-Schrodinger method when the total Hamiltonian as $H=H_0 +H'$ where the first term is known and the second term is proportional to a $\lambda$ which we can then write an expansion.

My understanding of the method is a bit superficial though. Because if I try to apply this to the double-well written as $V=(1/2)x^2(1-\sqrt{g}x)^2$ then my algorithm gets confused. Yes, if g goes to zero we recover the solvable problem but how does the expansion work? in powers of $g$ or $\sqrt{g}$? what do the energy terms look like?

I found very few discussions on multiple parameters but I have a feeling those methods are overkill for what I have here and I must be overlooking some trivial manipulation.

Comment: What do you want to calculate? Energy, wavefunction?

Comment: Energy, especifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The potential you presented has roots at $x=0$ and $x=1/\sqrt{g}$. Inspecting further, observe that it is symmetric around the midpoint $x=1/(2\sqrt{g})$. In other words, we need to shift the potential by this amount. That means we look at the potential
$$V(x+1/(2\sqrt{g}))=1/(32g)-x^2+gx^4/2.$$
To answer the question, I think yes the perturbation theory is done as an expansion in $g$, not $\sqrt{g}$, which agrees with the literature.

Good luck!